# Error (10818): Can't infer register because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge

Tags: asynchronous, vhdl, counter, quartus

I have been trying to implement an asynchronous counter, and the simulations are correct, but I keep on getting this error from Quartus

> Error (10818): Can't infer register for "encoderCounta[0]" at EncoderComputation.vhd(35) because it does not hold its value outside the clock edge.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
GPIO_0(1) <= encoderBits(0);
GPIO_0(3) <= encoderBits(1);
GPIO_0(5) <= readPosition;
GPIO_0(7) <= clk;


PROCESS(a)
BEGIN
    IF (rising_edge(a)) THEN
        IF (b = '0') THEN
            IF (encoderCounta = 399) THEN
                encoderCounta <= 0;
            ELSE 
                encoderCounta <= encoderCounta + 1;
            END IF;
        ELSIF(b = '1') THEN
             IF (encoderCounta = 0) THEN
                encoderCounta <= 399;
             ELSE
                encoderCounta <= encoderCounta - 1;
             END IF;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        IF(b = '1') THEN
             IF (encoderCounta = 399) THEN
                encoderCounta <= 0;
             ELSE
                encoderCounta <= encoderCounta + 1;
             END IF;
        ELSIF (b = '0') THEN
             IF (encoderCounta = 0) THEN
                encoderCounta <= 399;
             ELSE
                encoderCounta <= encoderCounta - 1;
             END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END PROCESS;


result <= encoderCounta;
```

Comment: Can you describe in your own words how `encoderCounta` is supposed to react to `a` and `b`?

Comment: Your tool is complaining you're trying to both assign encoderCounta on a clock edge and asynchronously. Without qualifying an assignment with a clock edge an assignment such as `encoderCounta <= encoderCounta + 1;` is a combinatorial loop (a relaxation oscillator with a delay provided by the increment). Should you get past the error you'll see a warning about the combinatorial loop. The simulations appear correct because only a is in the sensitivity list.

Comment: What is the `ELSE` supposed to do after `IF (rising_edge(a))`? You need to lose it altogether to make this synthesisable, which is exactly what the error message is telling you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VHDL Error (10818): Can't infer register](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907580/vhdl-error-10818-cant-infer-register)

Comment: There are many existing questions on this topic. Search for "bad synchronous description". Your code needs to match a template like http://stackoverflow.com/a/34067908/4090959 for it to be synthesis-eligible.

Comment: We are missing the assignment of `a` and `b` (you should give them better names). Also the `else` statement is really funny, like Brian Drummond says. What do you want the asynchronous counter to do? I see a clock.... the whole process triggers on `a`. Also synthesis software can really have problems making asynchronous logic.

Answer (score 4):

When you want a synthesizable code, code the way it will infer desired hardware.

A register is supposed to change value only on clock edge and keep the value till next clock edge. You say `IF (rising_edge(a))` assign some value, which is ok. But then you have put an else! You are also assigning some values to counter when it is not rising edge. This is not how a register works. If it is not rising edge, do NOT change value, i.e. remove that else part.